# using c# variable in javascript Google analytics, variable scope

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics

We are attempting to use the following code to pass order details to google analytics.  I read several posts that were very close, but was not able to resolve my issue.  The problem is in the definition or use of variable "item".  The line towards the bottom:  **'name': '<%= item[0] %>',** errors saying "item does not exist in current context".

I appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

```
 function TrackOrderLines() {
       var orderLines = "<%= GetOrderLines() %>";
       if (orderLines !='') {
           var items = orderLines.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] !='') {
            var item = items[i].split('|');

//This is here just to prove that we are getting the correct value in item.
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = item[0];

        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
            'id': '<%# salesOrder.OrderType + "-" + salesOrder.OrderNumber.ToString() + "-" + salesOrder.Company %>',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
            'name': '123',    // Product name. Required.
            **'name': '<%= item[0] %>',**
            //'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
            //'price': '111',                 // Unit price.
            //'quantity': '123'                   // Quantity.
});
                       }
                 }
          }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that `item` is actually a JS variable, but you're trying to print it from C# using `<%= %>`

Please try this:

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
            'id': '<%# salesOrder.OrderType + "-" + salesOrder.OrderNumber.ToString() + "-" + salesOrder.Company %>',                     // Transaction ID. Required.

            'name': item[0],
            //'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
            //'price': '111',                 // Unit price.
            //'quantity': '123'                   // Quantity.
});
```

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out.  We've tried several variations trying to get this to work and overlooked that.